# I've got FairlyLocal, but I need it for a project in VB but the function _() is not supported

Tags: c#, vb.net, namespaces

I've found this nice library to make localization in a .NET application. Problem is, this FairlyLocal is build in C#. Now I downloaded a convertor to make it happen in VB.NET.

But it seems my project is using the FairlyLocal.dll which is a binary and uses `_()` where `'_'` is the name of the function.

All I want is to change the `'_'` to `'t'` so it would work with the VB.NET application too.

How is this possible. I'm a greeny to VB.NET and .NET overall so please don't be rude.

Edit:
For example I got a login page with a h1:

```
<ASP:CONTENT ID="content2" CONTENTPLACEHOLDERID="heading" RUNAT="server">
    <% _("This is a heading") %>
</ASP:CONTENT>
```

Problem I get is at the `'_'`: `Identifier expected`
I also tried what Justin said (with the brackets `[]`) but that doesn't work eiter.

Comment: Can you give more details ir code sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since only the source is distributed, assuming [this](http://www.fairtutor.com/fairlylocal/fairlylocal-download) is where you got it from, just change the method name from `_` to `t` in your `InternationalPage` and `InternationalMaster` classes. Then, build the library and use it in your VB.NET application.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it will work, but you may be able to call the function named `_` from VB.NET by enclosing it in square brackets.  This is more often used when an identifier has the same name as a VB.NET keyword -- it may not work with all symbols.  Something like:

```
result = obj.[_]()
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't convert it. Just build it in C# and add it as a reference in your project. From there you'll be able to use it as if it was written in vb.net

Comment: Yes I know that, but when I use that dll, VB.NET doesn't allow to call a function with _("string")